# Prove that any natural number $n$ has a multiple lesser than $n^4$ so that its decimal notation contains at most 4 distinct integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example: $53764$ has a multiple $268820$, which contains 4 distinct digits $0$, $2$, $6$ and $8$. $3704111$ has a multiple $11112333$, which contains the digits $1$, $2$ and $3$. I need to prove that this is true for any natural number $n$. I have tried solving it with congruences (it seems related to the fact that every natural number has a multiple that can be expressed solely with '$0$'s and '$1$'s), but I'm stuck. Any hint or a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @RobertIsrael it was a homework for maths competition training

Comment: Hint: Consider all not too long integers consisting of $0$ and $1$ only. Then two of them have the same remainder modulo $n$ and their difference consists of $8,9,0,1$ only.

Comment: @fedja just what I needed. I don't know how I didn't think of it before. Thank you so much.